# Heaps of trouble reinstalling GRUB

Tags: linux, fedora, grub

So I followed the mainstream instructions of mounting the directory and stuff, but my problem comes where the partition has two folders called “home” and “root00” and the dirs that you find inside the root partition are in “root00” like proc, bin, sbin, etc. and “home” has ayaanmag. This really complicates things when I'm trying to follow those instructions and while I'm clearly not an expert with this, I did try improvising the command to point where the root directory, but things didn't work out. Now I had an idea to move everything from root00 to the main directory, so it looks like you would expect it to, and it was obviously stupid, and I knew this, so I took an image of the partition using clonezilla, I have 0 clue on how to restore it and while moving the files there were a lot of permission errors and such, and I'm pretty sure the /bin/ didn't copy over then I tried again, but obviously that wasn't gonna work out. So I need help on where to go from here, restore the clonezilla image? Do something else to copy over the files? I have 0 idea. Also, the Linux partition is /dev/nvme1n1p3 btw and the /boot partition without a Fedora entry is /dev/nvme1n1p2, but obviously I had mounted these when trying to do this stuff. I am also using fedora 37 for the live boot and the losts system itself

Comment: "I followed mainstream instruction" tells us nothing. You need to *explicitly* write down what you did.  That applies for your whole post. You assume we can just guess what you did and what the results are. We can't. It's on you to provide this information.

Comment: You're talking bout "stuff". What kind of stuff is that? What is your problem and what are you trying to accomplish?